# integration of login form(fosuserbundle) in base.html.twig template

Tags: php, html, symfony, templates, twig

I'm working on a symfony project and i have the login form in the header of the base.html.twig template, and all my templates extend base.html.twig.

The problem is when I try to render any template it should always render data (_csrf_token,last_username,..).
So I want to be able to login at every page and it's not recommended to render data in all my templates.

Is there any solution?

**base.html.twig**

```
 <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

                        <input type="text" id="email-modal" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur | Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="password" required="required" name="_password" class="form-control" id="password-modal" placeholder="Mot de passe">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="remember"> <p class="text-center text-muted"> Se souvient de moi </p> </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                    </div>

                    <p class="text-center">

                        <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}"  class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Se connecter </button>
                    </p>

                </form>

                <p class="text-center text-muted">Vous n'avez pas encore un compte?</p>
                <p class="text-center text-muted"><a href="register.html"><strong>S'inscrire</strong></a></p>
```

**Controller.php**

```
    }
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
   // return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
    $session = $request->getSession();
    /* @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }

    if ($error) {
        // TODO: this is a potential security risk (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9523)
        $error = $error->getMessage();
    }
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME);

    $csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider') ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate') : null;



    return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
         'operations'=>$operations,

    ));
}

/**
 * Renders the login template with the given parameters. Overwrite this function in
 * an extended controller to provide additional data for the login template.
 *
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function renderLogin(array $data)
{
    $template = sprintf('default/index.html.twig', $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'));

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($template, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do it is to use symfony capability to render a view with method render with a controller in parameter.

In your case what you should do is to override the login.html.twig from FOSUserBundle with your form who display the login form only.

You can find how to do this [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html) if you don't know how.

Then in your base.html.twig you can call the controller of FOSUserBundle in charge of the login action with something like this :

```
{{ render(controller(
    'FOSUserBundle:Security:login'
)) }}
```

Or if you have override FOSUserBundle Controller

```
{{ render(controller(
    'YourAppBundle:Security:login'
)) }}
```

You can learn more about this  [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).
With this method you don't need to have all the login logic of you code in your indexAction. You can render data in your template when these data are here for security. csfr_token is a must have for secure login form and lastUsername is here for the user experience. lastUsername can be remove if you really want but it's just one more data and i think it's an user experience improvement.

Comment: thank's gabriel-diez for the answer I will try it ;)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly 2 solutions here :

First one (not sure of it), you create a controller that display the form login with all the variables and you render this controller in your base template.

Second one (better) you create your login form as service so you can use it anywhere

Comment: thanx a lot for replying